# How to make an alert pop up with Javascript only when an innerHTML is over 99?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, counter, innerhtml

First timer and javascript newbie here. I'm learning javascript a bit late, and I've run into a problem.
I have a counter that goes up by one when a user clicks a button. The code is here:

```
<script language="javascript">  
var cnt = 0;  
function cntClicks(){  
cnt = cnt + 1;  
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = cnt;  
}  
</script>  
<h1 id="test">0</h1>
<button onclick="cntClicks();">add 1</button>
```

So far it works, but I want an alert to pop up when someone clicks 100 times. I have no idea how to execute this, and also I would sincerely appreciate the answer included in HTML. This is because <strike>Wapka</strike> doesn't allow purely javascript files. Was I correct to think this would include an if statement focused on the innerHTML being > 99?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

However, instead of checking `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML`, converting it to a number, then comparing it to 99, I would recommend using `cnt` instead.

```
if(cnt>99){ 
  alert(something); 
  //do anything else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an `if` statement. But you can just test the `cnt` variable, you don't need to test the `innerHTML`.

```js
var cnt = 0;

function cntClicks() {
  cnt = cnt + 1;
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = cnt;
  if (cnt > 9) {
    alert("Too many clicks!");
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="test">0</h1>
<button onclick="cntClicks();">add 1</button>
```

I've used 9 clicks instead of 9 to make the demo easier to try.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your last comment until after post